# ExtJS 6 - How to upload a file without using form?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs5, extjs6, extjs6-classic

Ext JS provides [`fileuploadfield`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.File.html) which is bundled with a button to browse local files. I just need to upload a file using as soon as it is selected from local instead of using a submit button in order to trigger the post process. Could not find an event which is fired after the file is selected.

p.s. Actually, the version I use is **Ext JS 6** but I think the solutions based on previous versions do the work as well.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34048251/1845533

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use a form if you want to submit the file. Even if you want the button to be in a toolbar, you can enclose it in a form and it will still look like a normal toolbar button (you will need to specify the proper ui config for this).

Example:

```
dockedItems: [{
    dock: 'top',
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'form',
        padding: '10 0 0',
        url: 'submit/image',
        items: {
            xtype: 'filefield',
            buttonOnly: true,
            width: 100,
            buttonConfig: {
                text: 'Add logo',
                width: '100%',
                ui: 'default-toolbar-small'
            },
            listeners: {
                change: function (filefield) {
                    filefield.up('form').submit();
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Remove logo'
    }, '-', {
        text: 'Discard changes'
    }]
}]
```

Working fiddle example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1pdk

Answer (score 10):

Form is not required. You can use AJAX and FormData.

```
var file = s.fileInputEl.dom.files[0],
    data = new FormData();

data.append('file', file);

Ext.Ajax.request({
   url: '/upload/files',
   rawData: data,
   headers: {'Content-Type':null}, //to use content type of FormData
   success: function(response){ }
});
```

Online demo [here](https://ext4all.com/post/extjs-6-ajax-file-upload.html)

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with [scebotari's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990211/extjs-6-how-to-upload-a-file-without-using-form/41997536#41997536) that in your case embedding a form in the toolbar is probably the easiest solution, for the sake of answering the original question:

If you really cannot or do not want to use a form and you're not limited regarding browser support, have a look at the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

The idea is to read the file contents on the client side (JavaScript) and then send the data using a regular AJAX request.

Your code could look like that:

```
function (fileField) {
    var file = fileField.fileInputEl.dom.files[0],
        reader;

    if (file === undefined || !(file instanceof File)) {
        return;
    }

    reader = new FileReader();    
    reader.onloadend = function (event) {
         var binaryString = '',
             bytes = new Uint8Array(event.target.result),
             length = bytes.byteLength,
             i,
             base64String;

         // convert to binary string
         for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
             binaryString += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
         }

         // convert to base64
         base64String = btoa(binaryString);

         Ext.Ajax.request({
             url: 'save-file.php',
             method: 'POST',
             params: {
                 data: base64String
             }
         });
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

Comment: good spot, thanks for your contribution but getting the exception `MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request` since we have not configured the AJAX request as a multipart request.

Comment: That seems to be a configuration/implementation detail on your server-side then. I'm not on ExtJS 6 right now, so I'm not sure which Content-Type Ext.Ajax uses with `method: 'POST'`, but you should be able to inspect the request using your browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the event [change](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.File.html#event-change) on the fileuploadfield.

The code could look like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: 'Upload Panel',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'filefield',
        name: 'photo',
        fieldLabel: 'Photo',
        labelWidth: 50,
        msgTarget: 'side',
        allowBlank: false,
        anchor: '100%',
        buttonText: 'Select Photo...',
        listeners: {
            change: function (me, value, eOpts) {
                console.log('trigger upload of file:', value);
            }
        }
    }],
});
```

Fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1pd2

Comment: But it still depends on `form submission` - I do not use a `form`. The `file upload field` is just an item of my `toolbar`.